# CoreImage - CIColorCube giving awkward results when processed with Metal

Tags: swift3, core-image

I have a pretty straightforward setup with CIColorCube as per Apple docs. When filtering with the default, unmodified values, the output image is totally off - 99.9% of the image is transparent with only a few pixels here and there visible.

**UPDATE**

I've (partially) figured out what the problem was - I'm using Metal for my CIImage processing. When processed with in a standard OpenGL context everything works as expected.

The question is still valid - why processing `CIColorCube` filter in Metal Context the image is totally off?

Metal Context creation:

```
guard
    let device:MTLDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
else {
    return nil
}

let context = CIContext(
    mtlDevice: device
)
```

OpenGL Context creation:

```
let context = CIContext()
```

Comparison of output images:

[image]

**END OF UPDATE**

Code for standard CIColorCube:

```
let size = 64

var cubeData = [Float](repeating: 0, count: size * size * size * 4)

var rgb:[Float] = [0, 0, 0]

var offset = 0

for z in 0 ..< size {
    rgb[2] = Float(z) / Float(size) // blue

    for y in 0 ..< size {
        rgb[1] = Float(y) / Float(size) // green

        for x in 0 ..< size {
            rgb[0] = Float(x) / Float(size) // red

            cubeData[offset]   = rgb[0]
            cubeData[offset+1] = rgb[1]
            cubeData[offset+2] = rgb[2]
            cubeData[offset+3] = 1.0

            offset += 4
        }
    }
}

let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &cubeData, count: cubeData.count))

guard
    let colorCubeFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube")
else {
    return nil
}

colorCubeFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
colorCubeFilter.setValue(size, forKey: "inputCubeDimension")
colorCubeFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputCubeData")

guard
    let result = colorCubeFilter.outputImage
else {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from what you've got here. But this note from the filter docs might be relevant: *As with all color filters, this operation is performed in the working color space of the Core Image context (CIContext) executing the filter, using unpremultiplied pixel color values. If you see unexpected results, verify that your output and working color spaces are set up as intended.*

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a color space problem. I've tried setting the same color space for both the context and `CIColorCubeWithColorSpace` filter. Also, discarding color space altogether does not help.

Comment: Hm... best guess is there might be something going on with the way a Metal-backed context sets up its buffer formats. Definitely worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: That you fully explain what the "standard" color map was a huge help - why oh why didn't apple do this???